# continuous audio playing across different UIKit & SpriteKit scenes

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I have an app with multiple view controllers. Some of these ViewControllers' views are `UIView`s, others are `SKView`s. I want to starting audio playback from the second the user enters the game, and continue playing the same track without interruption, even when segue-ing from a VC to another. Is this possible?

Comment: You could run audio through AppDelegate except that I wouldn't do that.  You should stick to one view controller when you develop a game with SpriteKit.

Comment: @El Tomato,  that depends entirely on the app,  I have designed a few that was mostly UIKit based, but has a small window for mini games to exist.  Now these corporate apps that I work with,  so I can't link it to you in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AVPlayer instance for audio playback. To loop the audio track so it plays continuously you will have to check for the "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime" notification and restart the player.

If you want to play the track across multiple view controllers i suggest creating a class that holds the AVPlayer instance and controlls playback. Then simply create a static instance of the class to be able to access it allover your app.

```
import AVKit

class AudioManager {

    static var sharedInstance = AudioManager()

    private var player: AVPlayer?

    func play() {
        // TODO: Initialize AVPlayer with desired audio track & start playing
        // player = AVPlayer(...)
        player?.play()

        // Register for the did play to end time notification to loop audio
        if let item = player?.currentItem {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onPlaybackFinished), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: item)
        }
    }

    @objc private func onPlaybackFinished() {
        player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        player?.play()
    }

}

// to start playback from anywhere in your app
AudioManager.sharedInstance.play()
```

AVPlayer docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer